# Linq with join distinct and order by

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, sql-order-by

I have a query that does not seem to respect my order by clause at all,

can someone help me solve this please ?

```
   Dim Result = ((From z As lnkCategorySubCategory In dbContext.lnkCategorySubCategories
                   Join x As SubItem In dbContext.SubItems On x.Id Equals z.CategoryId
                   Join p As lnkItemsCategory In dbContext.lnkItemsCategories On z.CategoryId Equals p.ItemCategoryId
                   Order By z.IsHeadColumn Descending
                   Order By z.Order Descending
                   Select x.Name)).Distinct
```

Comment: Show an example of how the results currently look and another example showing how they should be ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that i wasn't select the columns i was choosing to order by so i needed to write something more like this to solve this problem

```
  Dim Result = ((From z As lnkCategorySubCategory In dbContext.lnkCategorySubCategories
                       Join x As SubItem In dbContext.SubItems On x.Id Equals z.CategoryId
                       Join h As lnkSubItemImageLink In dbContext.lnkSubItemImageLinks On x.Id Equals h.SubItemId
                       Join p As lnkItemsCategory In dbContext.lnkItemsCategories On z.CategoryId Equals p.ItemCategoryId
                       Select x.Name, h.ImageLink, z.IsHeadColumn, z.Order)).Distinct.OrderByDescending(
                       Function(u) u.IsHeadColumn).ThenBy(Function(j) j.Order).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Name, Function(h) h.ImageLink)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I cannot tell you what is causing your issue. If I were to take a wild guess however, I'd suggest you change this:

```
Order By z.IsHeadColumn Descending
Order By z.Order Descending
```

To this:

```
Order By z.IsHeadColumn, z.Order descending
```

Comment: The way you were doing the Order by here was correct, i  had no issue there either, my problem was 'not selecting' those columns i was performing the 'OrderBy on', please look at my answer for more info. thanks for taking the time to respond to this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel `orderby z.IsHeadColumn descending, z.Order descending` should work

Comment: The only reason I added this as a seperate answer is because I was wondering how "Order By" would even compile, considering that this is a query syntax(I cannot vote as of now).
And now that I have posted, let me just add this much, that you could use "ThenBy" extn method with method syntax.

Comment: Another thing which i felt was the join didn't look correct. Shouldn't it be 'Join x As SubItem In dbContext.SubItems On x.CategoryId Equals z.Id'?